# How can I make a 'trial version' of a matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

My aim is to make a GUI, then by using deploytool to make an exe file from it.
Since I don't want the user to be able to use it for ever I want to make it as a trial version meaning that it will work only for a certain time.

I thought maybe by somehow connecting to the user's computer clock and date, and using the code for a time limit, but I found some problems it this logic.

Any ideas, how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the computer's clock seems a reasonable way to go. Sure, the user than thwart that by changing the clock, but this will most likely create sufficient inconvenience that they rather pay the reasonable price of the software.

Simply put the following inside the `OpeningFcn` of your GUI

```
expiryDate = '2012-12-31';

if now > datenum(expiryDate)
    h = errordlg('please upgrade to a full license');
    uiwait(h)
    return %# or throw an error
end
```