# How can I add the feature in Matlab GUI Deploytool package that expires the package after a specific expiry date?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a ‘trial version’ of a matlab GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260256/how-can-i-make-a-trial-version-of-a-matlab-gui)

How can I add the feature in Matlab GUI Deploytool package that expires the package after a specific expiry date? For example I have made a package and I am giving it to the user for trial purposes so I want the package to expire after 15 days on the user's machine.

Comment: Assuming you want to block it after a fixed date, why don't you just wrap your code with an if statement, based on the current date.
It is not very robust, but might be sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: I dont this this is a duplicate. It looks like the OP doesn't want to define a hard deadline, but rather a deadline that is `n` days after the date of install.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted in [How can I make a 'trial version' of a matlab GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260256/how-can-i-make-a-trial-version-of-a-matlab-gui) is more or less correct.   If you want to set a hard deadline then use the solution posted here.

However, if you want to define a deadline that depends on the date of install this becomes trickier.  Basically you need to determine the date of install in a way that the user can't manipulate.  If you were to use the date that your program was installed to define the cut off date your user could uninstall and then re-install your program and voila, they would have another 15 days of use.

The correct way to do this is to issue license key with your software. Then setup a web server that responds to licensing requests from your software.  The server receives requests, looks up if the specified key is valid and then returns yes or no.   This requires substantially more work than the solution provided above, but it gives you as the developer much more control. Additionally because your program is phoning home you can collect useful information how your program is being used.